# Nan return value when using the MATLAB function dll ed in C#

Tags: c#, matlab, dll

I am using a MATLAB .dll ed function in my C# app.
this function gonna process on 12 picture and then return a matrix. when I run it in matlab it works correctly, but when I call the .dll version in my C# app, returns a matrix assigned by NAN !
However, when I give 7 or less picture to my app, the MATLAB function works.

this is my matlab code:

```
function[result]= HDRMakerFunc(numExposures, Exposures, Lambda, numSamples, PicPath)
imageList = dir(fullfile(PicPath,'*.jpg'));
D=imageList;

S = [D(:).datenum].'; 
[S,S] = sort(S);
S = {D(S).name};  % Cell array of names in order by datenum.

    weights = zeros(1,256);
    %make weight array
    for i=1:256
        weights(i) = weight(i,1,256);
    end
    % allocate resulting matrices
    zRed = zeros(numSamples, numExposures);
    zGreen = zeros(numSamples, numExposures);
    zBlue = zeros(numSamples, numExposures);
    %
    for i=1:numExposures
            % read the ith image
%             temp =strcat( PicPath,'\', imageList(i).name);
            temp =strcat( PicPath,'\',S{1,i});
            img = imread(temp);
            numPixels = size(img,1) * size(img,2);
            step = numPixels / numSamples;
            sampleIndices = floor((1:step:numPixels));
            sampleIndices = sampleIndices';
            % sample the image for each color channel
            [zRedTemp, zGreenTemp, zBlueTemp] = sampel(img, sampleIndices);
            % build the resulting, small image consisting
            % of samples of the original image
            zRed(:,i) = zRedTemp;
            zGreen(:,i) = zGreenTemp;
            zBlue(:,i) = zBlueTemp;
    end
    % Creating exposures matrix B
    B = zeros(size(zRed,1)*size(zRed,2), numExposures);
    for i = 1:numExposures
        B(:,i) = reallog(Exposures(i));
    end

    % solve the system for each color channel
    % result[3][2]; % row = g col = lE  RGB
    % solve the system for each color channel
    [gRed,lERed]=gsolve(zRed, B, Lambda, weights);
    pause(5);
    [gGreen,lEGreen]=gsolve(zGreen, B, Lambda, weights);
    pause(5);
    [gBlue,lEBlue]=gsolve(zBlue, B, Lambda, weights);
    pause(5);
    result = {-gRed,lERed, -gGreen,lEGreen,-gBlue,lEBlue};

    y = (0:255);
    figure
    hold on
    subplot(2,2,1)
    plot(result{1},y, 'r-');
    xlabel('log Exposure X');
    ylabel('Pixel Value Z');

    subplot(2,2,2)
    plot( result{3},y, 'g');
    hold on
    % plot(gGreen, y, 'r*');
    xlabel('log Exposure X');
    ylabel('Pixel Value Z');

    subplot(2,2,3)
    plot( result{5},y , 'b-');
    xlabel('log Exposure X');
    ylabel('Pixel Value Z');

    figure
    y = (0:255);
    plot( result{1}, y );
    hold all
    plot( result{3} , y);
    fig = plot( result{5} ,y);

    save ('gResult','result');
end
```

and also if the exposure times be high, it does not work :|

I Compiled it with matlab coder, .NET assmebly type . is there any body to figure out why this problem occurs?!
thanks.

Comment: Could you give more information about what you're doing in the code, how you're compiling your C# app and linking the dll, and how you're calling it from C#?

Comment: in the MATLAB code, read 12 images and then sampling them,and pass each color channel to the gsolve function. out put of this function is a 1*256 and 90*1 matrices. output of my function is a cell that contain 3 of that matrices. when compiling this function to the .net assembly, give the .dll version. in C# app, add this .dll in references, using it in the main, new one object from, and use the function. give the input parameters as a mwarray, and output of this one is NaN...

Comment: Did you try calling a Matlab code that wouldn't do anything (or just `Hello World!` or something close), just to check if the mistake comes from the code or from linking the dll and the C# code? Also, when I asked you to be a bit more precise, I meant could you provide a Minimum Working Example, or at least some of the code? You can edit your question to include all this information so that it's easily accessible to anyone who would want to answer your question... How do you compile by the way? Using command line or Visual Studio?